# Why doesn't gradient text work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make gradient text with javascript and CSS.
The text is not showing, and if I remove -webkit-background-clip, the text is black, not gradient.
Here is my code:

```js
let gradientText = document.getElementById('title');
gradientText.style.background = '-webkit-linear-gradient(#ccc, #000)';
```

```css
#title {
    font-size:40px;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Gradient text</h1>
```

Comment: "*The text is not showing.*" ... do you understand exactly what `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent` does (quick litmus test: can you explain in layman's terms what it accomplishes)? Have you read the [documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color)?

Comment: The text is showing, just it's transparent :) did you try to select the text?

Comment: @esqew Yes, and i've seen it used for gradient text in many places

Comment: @Icepickle the text does select but I can't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have also set the webKitBackgroundClip in your js code to make it work:

```js
let gradientText = document.getElementById('title');
gradientText.style.background = '-webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333)';
gradientText.style.webkitBackgroundClip = 'text'; // this is important
```

```css
#title {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ccc, #000);
    font-size:40px;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Gradient text</h1>
```

Comment: … or, you simply have to stop overwriting more than intended in the first place :-) Despite `-webkit-background-clip` using the vendor prefix syntax, it is actually setting `background-clip` - so assigning a new value to the `background` shorthand property, will overwrite this with the _default value_ for background-clip. So only the restriction of the gradient to the actual background sub-property would be needed here: `gradientText.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333)';`

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull advice CBroe. Totaly forgot about the fact that background is actually a shorthand

Comment: @MartinGodzina me too :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you've got your rules applied a bit out-of-order. Set the `background` property before setting the background clipping and text fill colors:

```css
#title {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ccc, #000);
    font-size:40px;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Gradient text</h1>
```

Comment: It does appear, but the text is black, not gradient

Comment: @pineapplerind0215 - I've updated my answer to reflect your updated question text.

Comment: This will be broken after the background property is rewriten with the js snippet in the question